# Sum only one instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What I want to do with my query is to get the count of `hoursbilled`. I want to first check `#worked` but if data does not exist in that table I want to pull the data from `#workschedule`.

My issue is it seems to be totalling my data twice, i.e. if it exists in both tables it counts `hoursbilled` twice. This works fine on my test data, but when I roll it out to my production data this issue occurs. Is this an incorrect join, or bad query set-up? What do I need to do so that I can get an accurate count of `hoursbilled`?

Essentially what my query is trying to do is:

- If the date exists in the table `#worked` use the `hoursbilled` from that table
- If the date does not exist then use the `hoursbilled` from `#workschedule`

---

```
Create Table #workschedule
(
    caldate date
    ,isworkday varchar(5)
    ,hoursbilled int
)

Insert Into #workschedule Values
('01/01/2000', 'yes','3'), ('01/02/2000', 'yes','3'), ('01/03/2000', 'yes','1'),
('01/04/2000', 'no','0'), ('01/05/2000', 'yes','12'), ('01/06/2000', 'no','0')

Create Table #worked
(
    d1 date
    ,hoursbilled int
)
Insert Into #worked Values
('01/01/2000','2'), ('01/02/2000','4')

Declare @begin date, @end date
Set @begin = '01/01/2000'
Set @end = '01/08/2000'

Select 
ws.caldate,
case when wk.d1 = ws.caldate then wk.hoursbilled else ws.hoursbilled end
FROM #workschedule ws
Left Join #worked wk
ON ws.caldate = wk.d1
where ws.isworkday = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Do you have an actual example of it doing it twice? Also, your case statement can be simplified with `COALESCE(wk.hoursbilled, ws.hoursbilled)`

Comment: @ZLK - let me compose some temp tables from my production data and i'll edit.  I thought Coalesce returned the 1st non null value, I would have never thought of doing such in this instance...

Comment: It does return the first non-null value but since the condition for the case statement is the same as the condition for your join, COALESCE works fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @begin and @end are not used in your query at all. Few questions might help narrow down the issue:

. Do you have another predicate to limit the time?
. Do you aggregate on `caldate` after the join?
. Do you have duplicated entries in #workschedule and #worked with same 'caldate'? E.g. whether you have 'unique' constraint on the 'caldate' for both #workschedule and #worked table?

Here is an example of potential reason producing double counts:

```
/*
create database test

use test

-- drop table #workschedule
Create Table #workschedule
(
    caldate date
    ,isworkday varchar(5)
    ,hoursbilled int
)

Insert Into #workschedule Values
('01/01/2000', 'yes','3'), ('01/02/2000', 'yes','3'), ('01/03/2000', 'yes','1'),
('01/04/2000', 'no','0'), ('01/05/2000', 'yes','12'), ('01/06/2000', 'no','0'),
('01/01/2000', 'yes', '0') -- dup entry

-- drop table #worked
Create Table #worked
(
    d1 date
    ,hoursbilled int
)

Insert Into #worked Values
('01/01/2000','2'), ('01/02/2000','4'), 
('01/01/2000', '5') -- dup entry
*/

Declare @begin date, @end date
Set @begin = '01/01/2000'
Set @end = '01/08/2000'

-- Here 2000/01/01 counted duplicated, should only account for 7, but got 14.
--2000-01-01    14
--2000-01-02    4
--2000-01-03    1
--2000-01-05    12
Select 
    ws.caldate,
    sum(
        case 
            when wk.d1 = ws.caldate then wk.hoursbilled 
            else ws.hoursbilled 
        end
    ) hoursBilled
FROM #workschedule ws
    Left Join #worked wk
        ON ws.caldate = wk.d1
where 
    ws.isworkday = 'Yes' 
    and ws.caldate between @begin and @end
group by ws.caldate
order by ws.caldate
```